# Смена адреса WebView

Tags: activity, android, android-intent, webview

Здравствуйте! =)
Есть Android WebView.
Есть меню. Списки меню открывают Activity со списком кнопок. Каждая кнопка - определенная ссылка.
Нужно по тапе на кнопку:
Закрыть текущее активити и в 1м активити (оно же WebView) открыть ссылку. 
Суть вопроса: как передать новую ссылку, не давая приложению прав открытия всех сторонних ссылок? Средствами intent (?) с передачей параметра исключительно такому-то com.package.name?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Запускаем второе `Activity` посредством метода [`startActivityForResult()`](http://bit.ly/1o4rAVn), где можно указать `request code`.
2. При нажатии кнопки во втором `Activity` возвращаем адрес в первое `Activity` вызовом [`setResult()`](http://bit.ly/1kNqsdC).
3. В первом `Activity` переопределяем [`onActivityResult()`](http://bit.ly/1pEb9UV) и в нём ожидаем результата из второго `Activity`, при получении которого, извлекаем адрес для загрузки в `WebView` из `Intent`'а, передающегося одним из параметров в `onActivityResult()`.
4. Загружаем полученный адрес в `WebView`.

Чуток наколеночного кода, дабы было понятнее:

**Первое `Activity`:**

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int SOME_REQUEST_ID = 1234;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Open another activity.");
        setContentView(button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class), SOME_REQUEST_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if ((requestCode == SOME_REQUEST_ID) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Load " + data.getStringExtra("url") + " in WebView.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Второе `Activity`:**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Pick URL and return to previous activity.");
        setContentView(button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("url", "http://google.com/"));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно примером и ответить для нуба? Не понял ничего.

Comment: @MoNTE48, к сожалению, вряд ли у меня получится ответить ещё проще и подробнее, чем я это уже сделал. В особенности человеку, который не в состоянии даже по заботливо расставленным ссылкам в ответе пройтись.

Comment: @falstaf, я прошелся. Но мой английский не позволил мне понять тот контент.
Я бы не отказался от единичного примера аля
Активити1 с вебвьювером и обработкой button1 и активити2 с button2, которое выполнит передачу.
Это было бы лучше всех ссылок. Учусь на примерах.
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: @MoNTE48, добавил код.

Comment: @falstaf, спасибо. Но 
1) а где вебвьювер?
2) во втором активити несовсем понятно как добавить больше кода? У меня будет более 30 кнопок...

Comment: @MoNTE48, я вам показал, как из второго `Activity` передать что-то в первое на примере одной кнопки и `Toast`'а. В чём сложность адаптировать это под вашу задачу? Замените вывод получаемого от второго `Activity` URL'а в `Toast`'е на загрузку этого адреса в `WebView`.